# How to add a contact on the device only?

Tags: contacts

WHenever I try and add a contact, it only gives me the option to choose which account to add it with.

How do I get the 'on this device' option?

Comment: Many modern Android devices do not have this option anymore in their stock ROM, it is device dependant, or ROM dependant if you use a 3rd party ROM. Perhaps if you have details of what device and Android version you are using, we could be of more assistance.

Comment: @acejavelin latest version, nexus 6p

Comment: Related: [Add contact without using “Google account”?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24331/16575)

Answer (score 0):

On some devices, the "local phonebook" simply doesn't exist. But you can add it, e.g. using an app like [MyLocalAccount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.mylocalaccount). Here's this app's description from *Google Play:*

> This app does represent a local contact account. This is helpfully for devices without local contact account (f.e. Nexus series) if you don't want to sync your contacts with Google servers. These contacts can be synced then f.e. with MyPhoneExplorer to your PC.

If you wonder why *MyPhoneExplorer* is mentioned here: the app is from the same developer, so a well-known one. It wasn't updated for a while, but I've not yet found an alternative to it. Worth a try at least – it's free.

Comment: Will this work with other apps?  Like if whatsapp says it wants to access my contacts, will it have access to MyLocalAccount?

Comment: I have not tried that myself, but I'd suppose so. If it's accessible from the contacts app (which it is, or it wouldn't make any sense) it should also be available from other apps having the corresponding permissions to read contacts. To my understanding, it integrates with the contacts provider. As the app is available for free, why not simply test it out? Let us know then, so we can be sure :)