# Android 9, google accounts without using google account?

Tags: applications

i need help, with google contacts.

The phone is using google contacts and dialer (Android 9). I want to import contacts TO PHONE, but google contacts app allows only import to gmail acc.

Is there some solution? I do not want to use google servicies for syncing and storing my contacts, calls and messages.

Thank you

- e.g. something like local account on windows 10
- was helpful but apps are very old and not updated [Add contact without using "Google account"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24331/add-contact-without-using-google-account)

Comment: Import your contacts from vcf files: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/am.ed.importcontacts/

Comment: Thank you. Sounds easy, but could google have access to the contacts?

Comment: If you have added an Google account on that device you can configure it in the account settings what should be synchronized. This allows you to disable contacts sync. How effective this is if you want to prevent Google to see you contacts I don't know.

Comment: Vell, somehow i set that it save into device, I tried that app. import contacts, but it imported badly, and created multiple copies of one contact.

Answer (score 0):

i have had this problem on some Xiaomi devices. even when added contacts offline (with MyPhoneExplorer) it switched automatically into google when device goes online. i bet it is the contacts app per design not allowing local contacts.

i ended up with 3rd party contacts app (like [com.simplemobiletools.contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.contacts))

Comment: Thank you. Well, it is exactly Redmi note 8 pro. I do not want to risk flashing to Indian ROMs to use manufacturer apps. I will try it, Maybe i will buy Pro version.

Answer (score 0):

Partialy solved. - no need 3. party apps
For Xiaomi devices with google contacts, google dialer, google sms.
In settings turned off several google servicies permisions to these apps.
After some warnings and problem with opening contacts app. Finally it opened, without option to choose google account.

Now in app were 2 options device and mi account.
When importing contacts with using google contacts, i choosed: Device.
Now contacts appear to be saved in mi account

After removing mi account from phone contacts were imported into device succesfuly.
 - again when logged in contacts were under mi account (so turn off sync)

Depends on device, some google servicies have to be turned back on beacuse of calling and sending messages - (could have different names)